# How do I get the time of app getting started?

Tags: ios, xcode

while testing my app i have started by Command+R with Xcode. after few minutes I needs to know when it is started It  may look like simple But without using any NSLog message at the time of launch I am unable to get the starting time of the app started. Is there any log files exists to show this Even in Console i dint get any traces.

Comment: in ur `applicationDidFinishedlaunching`, NSLog([[NSDate date]description])

Comment: @samfisher Or rather `NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate date]);` in case the description of the date contains characters that can be mistaken for format specifiers, making `NSLog()` invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a `startTime` property in Appdelegate of NSDate type. In `applicationDidFinishedlaunching` set the value as `self.startDate = [NSDate date];`. Whenever you need to access the value, you can get it by `((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).startDate`

If you want to see this anytime during testing, just click the pause button on debug area and execute the debugger command:

```
po [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) startDate]
```

If you want to see the value at end of running you can log the value in `applicationWillTerminate:` or `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks.. It have help for the next time.I had been testing for about 2 hours and wanna know the time of start when stop the app or now. for calculating the running time.